# incrementing an object in a while loops

Tags: javascript, object, while-loop, increment

**input:** `["doc", "doc", "image", "doc(1)", "doc"]`

**output:** `["doc", "doc(1)", "image", "doc(1)(1)", "doc(2)"]`

**The issue:**

`{used[name]++}` this part of the code is tricking me.

I don't understand line and how I'm not assigning 1 to the first thing

the code is working the way it should from trial and error; but I'm having a hard to wrapping my brain around this loop.

**my understanding:**

we loop through the names, then each name that starts with docs; we assign newName to doc1

**What I tried:**

`used[newName] = 6;`

results:
[doc, doc(6), image, doc(1), doc(7)]

this ended up confusing me more. it's late and I might just need some sleep.

---

```
const solution = names => {
    const used = {};
    return names.map(name => {
        let newName = name;
        while (used[newName]) {
            newName = `${name}(${used[name]++})`;
        }
        used[newName] = 1;
        return newName;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time a name is encountered `used[newName]` is `undefined`, so the `while` loop doesn't even start, and `newName` is returned. In the next time it's encountered, you already have `user[newName]=1`, so `(1)` is appended to the name, and so on.